# How to insert java String value into MySQL TEXT data type?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I am building a basic web crawler. I am using `mysql-connector` to connect to the database where I am planning to store the data. I am unable to insert `TEXT` data types from a plain java `String`.

When I try to insert the `String` I get this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Method com/mysql/jdbc/PreparedStatement.setCharacterStream(ILjava/io/Reader;)V is abstract
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.setCharacterStream(PreparedStatement.java)
    at WebCrawler.insertIntoChecked(WebCrawler.java:179)
    ...
```

I was able to insert text files (.txt) into `TEXT` data types using `FileReader` and method .setCharacterStream() before. However I can't do that with a `String`. I have tried converting it to `StringReader` and later to `BufferedReader`, but I still got the same error.

`data.head` is a `String` that contains the head of the html page and `data.body` contains the body of the html page.

`head` and `body` attributes (mysql table) are `MEDIUMTEXT`, every other attribute is `varchar(x)`

Method that inserts the data into database:

```java
private void insertIntoChecked(SiteData data){
        try {
            String sql =
                    "INSERT INTO checked " +
                            "(URL,title,language, charset, content, head, body)" +
                            "VALUES " +
                            "(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);";
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            preparedStatement.setString(1, data.url);
            preparedStatement.setString(2, data.title);
            preparedStatement.setString(3, data.language);
            preparedStatement.setString(4, data.charset);
            preparedStatement.setString(5, data.content);
            BufferedReader sr1 = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(data.head));
            BufferedReader sr2 = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(data.body));
            preparedStatement.setCharacterStream(6, sr1); // the part that is causing the problem
            preparedStatement.setCharacterStream(7, sr2); // ^
            sr1.close();
            sr2.close();
            preparedStatement.execute();
            preparedStatement.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I've never tried inserting a clob into a MySQL database. I can tell you that in Oracle you insert an `EMPTY_CLOB()`. Once the row is inserted you get a reference to this CLOB; from the reference you get a `Writer`; then it's just a matter of using the writer. It could be similar. The interesting part is that the insert happens first, the LOB data is streamed later (during the same transaction).

Answer (score 0):

This looks like you're trying to use a JDBC 4.0 feature using a driver version that doesn't support this.

You should be using Connector/J 5.1 or higher if you want to make use of `setCharacterStream`, and I suspect you're using an older version.

Refer to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-implementation-notes.html for more information.